# Serialize Point from postgresql database to Java object

Tags: spring, hibernate, deserialization, postgis

Which format should a postgresql field be retrieved in, for Hibernate to automatically deserialize it into an `org.postgis.Point`, or more generally an `org.postgis.Geometry` object?

Example:

```java
@Formula("ST_PointOnSurface(surface)::geometry")
private Point pointOnSurface;
```

I have tried to wrap the above expression in `ST_AsGeoJson`, `ST_AsBinary` and other functions, but all result in the following exception when attempting to deserialize:

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2775)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1741)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1667)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1556)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:985)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
    at my.confidential.package.name.MyEntityDaoImpl.getAll(MyEntityDaoImpl.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1168.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45009)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45012)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 30313031
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:866)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

- PostgreSQL 12.3 with `postgis` extension
- The column `surface` is of type `geometry`
- Java 8
- `net.postgis:postgis-geometry:2.5.0`
- `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final`
- Hibernate 5.2.4
- Spring 4.3.25

Comment: I don't know why someone (Samuel Liew) deleted my answer for this question. Let me write it again: Use hibernate spatial. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-spatial

Comment: @OnurBaştürk thank you. Now I have this related question: can I inject my own types into JDBC somehow, just like hibernate-spatial injects the `Geometry` types to work out-of-the-box, converting automatically between database representation and java object? Without using `@Converter`?

Comment: Well mapping custom types is much more complex than simple types but you can still do  it using Hibernate. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types

Comment: @OnurBaştürk You may post your comment as an answer to receive the bounty.

Comment: I posted it as answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use hibernate spatial. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-spatial
2. Mapping custom types is much more complex than simple types but you can still do it using Hibernate. Check out baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types